# How To Connect To A WCF Service Using IP Of The Host Machine Where The Service Is Hosted?

Tags: wcf

I have a secured WCF service (https://MachineName:sslport/services) self hosted in a machine. Different instances of same service are deployed in differnt machines. From a client app, I am able to connect to theses services thru code ie) using ChannelFactory() with the same endpoint address. But if i try to access the service using the endpoint address as (https://ipaddress:sslport/services) replacing machines name with machine ipaddress, i am getting some error stating "couldnot establish trust relationship". I know this is an error caused by ssl certificate that it couldnot establish a trust relationship.

Is there any settings or any possible ways to bring this working? Please guide if anyone knows about this.

Answer (score 1):

SSL certs are based on names which means the validation of a SSL cert will fail when tried with an IP address instead of a name.

You could change the validation to always succeed - this is not a config but someabout 1-5 lines of code... BUT this is ABSOLUTELY NOT the way to go since it defeats the whole purpose of haven an SSL cert in the first place because then any and every SSL cert (forged, self-signed etc.) would be accepted as fine...

Perhaps if you tell WHY you would want to do this there is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to allow me to bypass the default authentication...

Just before I connect, I hook up this CallBack.

```
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateRemoteCertificate);
```

Then within the 'ValidatRemoteCertificate'

```
    private static bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors policyErrors)
    {
        if (policyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None) return true;
        if (cert.Subject == "CN=whatever.address.com") return true;
        return false;
    }
```

You can include as many addresses as you like.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yahia, the code I suggested above explicitly allows a single name 'whatever.address.com', I'm not suggesting that he returns 'true' for every address. If you know that the domain is valid, regardless of the state of the certificate, then surely it's ok to accept it (unless I'm missing something).